# Installing NodaTime 2.2.x in PCL with Profile44

Tags: nodatime

I am working on a PCL project that is using Profile44 as TargetFrameworkProfile. When I try to install NodaTime 2.2.4 I get the following error message:

```
Could not install package 'NodaTime 2.2.4'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETPortable,Version=v4.6,Profile=Profile44', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.
```

Do I have to downgrade to .Net 4.5 or what options do I have?

Comment: Profile 44 corresponds to netstandard1.2 by the looks of it, whereas Noda Time 2.0 requires netstandard1.3. Have you tried using Noda Time 1.4.x instead? That *may* work - I'm not sure.

Comment: NodaTime 1.4.x works. However, I will check to migrate the PCL to a netstandard 1.3 compatible library. Thank you for your response.

Comment: Righto - I'll write this up as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Noda Time 2.x only supports the Target Framework Monikers `netstandard1.3` and `net45`. There's no direct PCL support, although some environments that traditionally used PCLs now support .NET Standard.

The 1.x series supports PCLs via Profile328, which has a NuGet target of "portable-net4+sl50+win8+wpa81+wp8". For environments that don't yet support .NET Standard, trying the 1.x series is the best option.

Note that I'm expecting Noda Time 3.0 to *probably* target `netstandard2.0`, although I'll still keep the older versions up to date with respect to time zone data.